# Pointwise ergodic theorem & amenable semigroups

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, semigroups, amenability

[Lindenstrauss](http://www.ams.org/journals/era/1999-05-12/S1079-6762-99-00065-7/S1079-6762-99-00065-7.pdf) proved **pointwise ergodic theorem** for **amenable groups** using tempered folner sequence.

Is there a pointwise ergodic theorem for **amenable semigroups** such as $\mathbb{N}^2$?

Comment: Do you care about general amenable semigroups or just $\mathbb{N}^2$?

Comment: @Blackbird I would really like to know about general amenable groups.